# An anime where the male protagonist has to wear cat ears

Tags: sands-of-destruction

I watched this anime dubbed on Netflix about 3/4 years ago. It's set in a magical fantasy world. There is a human who works in a pub, but he has to wear cat ears or else he is hunted. Then there is this really cool character who crashes in and takes him on an adventure.

In the first episode, they left on a boat that they either stole or made themselves, with a talking animal thing while the police are going after them.

I'm thinking that they are on a quest to find something or other. The guy who has to dress as a cat person is tall and slim, with light brown/dark blonde hair.
The main girl has long pinkish hair, and I believe she has powers and has an animal as her companion.

I have been searching for about 2/3 years and I am going mental. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Sands of Destruction]

The anime you are looking for is called [*Sands of Destruction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sands_of_Destruction). It was originally a Nintendo game and in 2008 it got an anime adaption.

It takes place in a world where humans serve as livestock for the ruling beastman. The boy in the bar is called Kyrie and the girl is Morte Ashela.

Comment: THIS IS IT!!!! THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!! YOU ARE A LEGEND! You have literally saved my mind!

Comment: ^^ you're very welcome, and lucky.  I literally watched the first episode days before you posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the anime you're searching is "Loveless".

it was on netflix, the main girl has pinkish hair and there's this [Koya Sakagami](http://loveless.wikia.com/wiki/Kouya_Sakagami) character who is forced to wear cat ears.

[Loveless Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loveless_(manga))

Comment: Can you expand further your answer and explain why is that the anime he is looking for?

Comment: it was on netflix, the main girl has pinkish hair and there's this http://loveless.wikia.com/wiki/Kouya_Sakagami who is forced to wear cat ears

Comment: @LeonelAraújo it is better if you [edit](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/18708/edit) that information in rather than leaving it as a comment